# Should I place a DSN (datasource) definition inside or outside onApplicationStart() function?

Tags: coldfusion, datasource, dsn, application.cfc

When is it appropriate to place DSN definitions inside the onApplicationStart() function vs outside of the function?

I have seen this method:

```
<cfset this.datasource = "datasource_name">
  <cffunction name="onApplicationStart" returnType="boolean" output="false">
```

and I've seen it this way...

```
<cffunction name="onApplicationStart" returnType="boolean" output="false">
  <cfset application.dsn = "datasource_name">
```

The only reasons I can find for this format is leaving the datasource outside the function is an older, still supported, but outdated way of doing things.

Is there any other reason for it?

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002299/application-cfc-setting-dsn-and-calling-that-dsn) already, but it only states where DSNs should be declared, but not when to it should go inside vs outside.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, if you do `this.datasource` then it is an application wide default. `<cfquery>` does not even need datasource specified.(a good thing). If you set an application wide variable, you have to specify the datasource in each and every `<cfquery>`, (a bad thing)

Comment: ... and in case it is not clear, the `this.datasource` syntax/property is actually newer than the old concept of using an `application.dsn` variable

Comment: I figured this might come down to just refactoring my application to account for CF2018. Thanks!

Comment: It should be a simple find and replace with nothing. I sometimes say, the code that does not exist, you do not maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: Should I place a DSN (datasource) definition inside or outside `onApplicationStart()` function?

A: Outside

That way `<cfquery>`, `QueryExecute()`, and ORM can tap into that datasource information without that information being repeated.